# Configuring New Relic for multiple application on a shared platform

Tags: newrelic, business-process-management

New Relic appears fairly straight forward when it comes to instrumenting a web application. However, I can't find any information on setting up new relic to work on a web application that hosts multiple "named applications".

For example, if you had a Wordpress install, and ran 4 different blogs against the same core install, how can you get new relic to segment the data per blog (rather than at the PHP class level which will be shared by all 4 blogs).  I am specifically working on the IBM BPMS platform, which is a Java application that allows teams to build (configure) projects on top of it. This means that when New Relic's Java agent is applied, it will report classes and jdbc calls, but it can't differentiate between the various application/projects, so there is no way to know which application/project is causing performance issues. The RUM has a similar issue, since the platform does not allow for friendly urls and all UIs are generated from a shared set of JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your applications into their own separate instances using your vhost configuration or through API calls. Whichever is most convenient for you.

There are some good documents describing this in New Relic's docs.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/php/per-directory-settings

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/php/the-php-api

Comment: That does a good job of answering the first part of my question, which I admit to writing it in a way that confused the topic. The approach you posted would seem to work well for scripted languages like PHP, but not compiled like Java.